# Suggestions for program/script to log hours

Tags: c++, linux, windows, logging, signals

This is a slightly open-ended question, but I'm looking for general guidance on how to approach this problem, because I don't really know where to start:

With my current employer, I need to log my working hours weekly. So I'm interested in writing a program (I'm most comfortable with C++) or a script to "invisibly" capture every time I log in to my machine and put it to sleep. Can the community recommend approaches for how to do this?

I'll describe my work environment a bit more:

I log in to a Windows box which I mostly use for email and web browsing, but most of my development is done by VNC'ing to a Linux box. So I log into the Linux box almost right away after logging in to Windows. The Linux box is my own, so I'm free to write binary/script daemons to run on it.

My first thought was to write a program that somehow "trapped" windows login and sleep events, similar to how you can trap for SIGINT, etc. - but I don't know if or how this is possible.

I'm quite new and naive to the Linux environment, so I don't know why this happens: but I'm not usually prompted for my password when I resume my VNC session (I usually see an error about a crash occurring with x-screensaver). I am *rarely* prompted for my password, though, but I don't yet know what differentiates between when I'm asked and when I'm not. The reason I mention this is because if there is such a thing as "trapping on login" it would seem infeasible to do on the Linux box because of this inconsistent password prompting.

Again: my goal is to have something that captures my login/logout/sleep activities *without* me launching a command/script each time I log in/out or put my system to sleep. If it's not reasonable to code/script a daemon that does this, are there off-the-shelf (and free) solutions that could do this? If not - i.e. if the only solution is manually running something every time I log in/out or put my system to sleep - then I'll be okay cobbling together a program to do so.

Thank you for pointers and advice.

Comment: The VNC server probably generates log files you could process. Failing that the login system probably logs logins.

Comment: @Galik: This looks promising; thank you. I had to enable logging with VNC Viewer (was not enabled by default), but it looks to be generating output from which I can extract the needed information. Thanks for this idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an interesting solution to this: the `Get-WinEvent` command in the Windows PowerShell. E.g.:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{starttime='1/20/2017';endtime='1/21/2017';logname='security';id=4648,4634}

TimeCreated                             ProviderName                                                                 Id Message
-----------                             ------------                                                                 -- -------
1/20/2017 6:20:38 PM                    Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing                                        4634 An account was logged off....
1/20/2017 5:42:20 PM                    Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing                                        4634 An account was logged off....
1/20/2017 5:42:20 PM                    Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing                                        4648 A logon was attempted using explicit...
1/20/2017 5:42:20 PM                    Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing                                        4634 An account was logged off....
1/20/2017 5:42:20 PM                    Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing                                        4648 A logon was attempted using explicit...
1/20/2017 5:42:20 PM                    Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing                                        4634 An account was logged off....
1/20/2017 5:42:20 PM                    Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing                                        4648 A logon was attempted using explicit...
1/20/2017 5:42:19 PM                    Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing                                        4634 An account was logged off....
1/20/2017 5:42:18 PM                    Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing                                        4648 A logon was attempted using explicit...
1/20/2017 5:30:32 PM                    Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing                                        4648 A logon was attempted using explicit...
1/20/2017 5:30:29 PM                    Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing                                        4648 A logon was attempted using explicit...
1/20/2017 4:34:36 PM                    Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing                                        4634 An account was logged off....
1/20/2017 2:49:34 PM                    Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing                                        4634 An account was logged off....
1/20/2017 2:07:06 PM                    Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing                                        4634 An account was logged off....
1/20/2017 1:48:06 PM                    Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing                                        4634 An account was logged off....
1/20/2017 1:48:06 PM                    Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing                                        4634 An account was logged off....
1/20/2017 1:45:09 PM                    Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing                                        4634 An account was logged off....
1/20/2017 1:45:09 PM                    Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing                                        4634 An account was logged off....
1/20/2017 1:42:55 PM                    Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing                                        4634 An account was logged off....
1/20/2017 1:42:54 PM                    Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing                                        4634 An account was logged off....
1/20/2017 12:56:32 PM                   Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing                                        4634 An account was logged off....
1/20/2017 12:16:58 PM                   Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing                                        4634 An account was logged off....
1/20/2017 12:16:58 PM                   Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing                                        4634 An account was logged off....
1/20/2017 12:16:58 PM                   Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing                                        4648 A logon was attempted using explicit...
1/20/2017 12:16:58 PM                   Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing                                        4634 An account was logged off....
1/20/2017 12:16:58 PM                   Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing                                        4634 An account was logged off....
1/20/2017 12:16:58 PM                   Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing                                        4648 A logon was attempted using explicit...
1/20/2017 11:23:29 AM                   Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing                                        4634 An account was logged off....
1/20/2017 10:06:22 AM                   Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing                                        4634 An account was logged off....
1/20/2017 9:48:06 AM                    Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing                                        4634 An account was logged off....
1/20/2017 9:48:06 AM                    Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing                                        4634 An account was logged off....
1/20/2017 9:45:19 AM                    Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing                                        4634 An account was logged off....
1/20/2017 9:45:09 AM                    Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing                                        4634 An account was logged off....
1/20/2017 9:43:47 AM                    Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing                                        4634 An account was logged off....
1/20/2017 9:43:47 AM                    Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing                                        4634 An account was logged off....
1/20/2017 9:43:47 AM                    Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing                                        4648 A logon was attempted using explicit...
1/20/2017 9:43:47 AM                    Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing                                        4634 An account was logged off....
1/20/2017 9:43:47 AM                    Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing                                        4634 An account was logged off....
1/20/2017 9:43:47 AM                    Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing                                        4648 A logon was attempted using explicit...
1/20/2017 9:43:25 AM                    Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing                                        4634 An account was logged off....
1/20/2017 9:42:57 AM                    Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing                                        4634 An account was logged off....
1/20/2017 9:42:56 AM                    Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing                                        4634 An account was logged off....
1/20/2017 9:42:52 AM                    Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing                                        4648 A logon was attempted using explicit...
```

Where 4648 represents a logon event, and 4634 represents a logoff event.

From here, I imagine the remainder of my desired goal is to wrap this up in some kind of script that calculates the time between the first logon and the last logoff.

I guess this could have gone to SuperUser, but I didn't know originally where the question/answer would lead.

Answer (score 2):

You could have a look at the "last" command. In [another stack overflow question](https://serverfault.com/questions/305738/how-do-i-extract-login-history#305739) this was mentioned as listing the login/logout times. On my machine this command also gave me values that looked like a duration (: I think).

If you want to look into possibilities of protocoling logins yourself, adding commands into the ".bashrc" lets you run custom commands whenever a shell is opened. This approach however runs the commands for every console you open, not just when you log in.

I guess looking into the "last" command can easily give you the results you want.

Comment: This looks promising; I wasn't aware of this command. I have a bit of research to do on how to work with this command, because the list of logins doesn't match what I'd expect, but this is a good jumping off point.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can always take the following simple solution if the situation is urgent and then move to a more sophisticated one later...Write a script in whatever work environment you are in, which measures time from start to action. You can trivially make it stop until you enter any input, and obtain how long it took until you provided this input.

Output these results in some text file and load them into some code to parse the results into a presentable format, would be interesting to do in a DBMS. Set the scripts into the scheduler to start automatically...

One problem I see here is the work environment. You say the Windows machine is your own, but do you want to log work hours on that? If so, it becomes a bit more complicated to automate the script to start when you read work-related emails... It would be much simpler to just set up the script on the Linux environment and maybe add an approximation of time spent on the Windows machine doing work-related stuff but you don't provide the limitations on the Linux machine which is not yours. Maybe you can also write a script which loads the machine and wraps the loading in a functionality measuring time until you close the machine... of course, this becomes annoying if you exit the machine often.

For sure there are more suitable ways to fully automate this process, though... depends on what exactly you want and what you are limited with, so take this as a pointer.

Comment: Setting up the script in the Linux environment would be fine...it doesn't need to be on the Windows box. To clarify: the Linux box is also my own, so perfectly okay for me to script/code on that box as well. I don't quite understand: with your idea, what event are you suggesting should trigger the script to write its start time to file?